# Allow passing a function with extended interface as parameter in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Working with React, I need to pass a bunch of function as props, and i'm having trouble using extended interface as parameter type for a function to be used in a "standard" component; so far I've been able to fix some of these issue by typing the component itself with generics, but it doesn't always does the trick.

Let's consider the following example, which is a simplified and react-less version of the issue:

```js
//my API sends me resources with Hydra format, which has mandatory properties e.g. `@type`.
interface HydraResource {
    '@type': string;
}

//of course these resources each have a different set of properties, here i add a numeric `id`
interface SpecificResource extends HydraResource {
    id: number;
}

//the following functions each take a resource to log a line in the console
function isHydra(resource: HydraResource) {
    console.log(`this is an hydra resource of type ${resource['@type']}`);
}
function isSpecificHydra(resource: SpecificResource) {
    console.log(`this is a specific hydra resource with id ${resource.id}`);
}

//now let's create a Specific resource
const resource: SpecificResource = {
    '@type': 'Specific',
    id: 1,
};

//so far, extending interface does the job
isHydra(resource);
isSpecificHydra(resource);

//now let's define a function with a Handler function as parameter
type Handler = (res: HydraResource) => void;
function askHydra(func: Handler, resource: HydraResource) {
    func(resource);
}

//this is ok
askHydra(isHydra, resource);
//but here, Handler type does not allow a function that takes a extended interface as parameter
askHydra(isSpecificHydra, resource);
```

On the last call, Typescript sends a warning saying:

```
Argument of type '(resource: SpecificResource) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Handler'.
  Types of parameters 'resource' and 'res' are incompatible.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'HydraResource' but required in type 'SpecificResource'.(2345)
```

Now, what i need is to find a way to tell TypeScript that Handler accept a parameter of type "extending HydraResource" so that i can pass a function accepting any kind of resource, but i can't seem to find a proper way to do it.

Any insight i could use is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

While typing the last bit of my issue, I had an idea that turned out working just fine.

In my typed React components i use `<T extend HydraResource>` as type, which is as a matter of fact exactly what i needed here, but i was wrongly trying to use it as parameter type directly. Instead, I modified my code as follow:

```js
type Handler<T extends HydraResource> = (res: T) => void;
function askHydra<T extends HydraResource>(func: Handler<T>, resource: T) {
    func(resource);
}
```

This, way i can simply specify what type of HydraResource function i want to pass to my component:

```js
askHydra<HydraResource>(isHydra, resource);
askHydra<SpecificResource>(isSpecificHydra, resource);
```

You can see [on this online TS editor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIE8AmU4CUIDOA9gK5RLIDeAUMncgOQACY6ADhAwFzIFhSgA5gG5qAX2rVQkWIhQBlDgmAxgCfMTIUIAD0ghMBNFhwbS5FDXrJgmHiBIBbAEbRRE6jBIgEYYERAbAgxsOAAKKEJzJB4Q0yitCABKKlp6BADiABsIADosokEwgAMwAAtgI0rkOECykzhkSM0LZCIYZFYOZAASSmboiABtZi7OAF0xYqT3SS8fPwCgxQhlVQQ48IHEnhW1tTNElKt0zKIc-MKS8urqxoIlFTVketCmhNaAd2Bym0xe-ofJC5WxTGbiSQZEB8d4tGLIPZPdRAlAAXlS1lG7E4PAYiPWDAANGk6LYeABGYliURSYINCIo8GVfFqTYMuHJGljNC1TA5KAAHgAKgA%20ZDo9k8IUpVFigBuRFsonmvn8gTgBAA1pthchdPpDMZQocLCKwirYrz%20cKRYTYYMpccScgVezBuCPBrtQ0BZsTUgzZVNnbthZwV6dSzkRzAwQo8H7UdREA) that it now compiles without any error.

Thanks you for rubber-ducking, you're great listeners

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the type!

```
//now let's define a function with a Handler function as parameter
type Handler<T extends HydraResource> = (res: T) => void;
function askHydra<T extends HydraResource>(func: Handler<T>, resource: T) {
    func(resource);
}

//function askHydra<SpecificResource>(func: Handler<SpecificResource>, resource: SpecificResource): void
askHydra(isHydra, resource);
//function askHydra<SpecificResource>(func: Handler<SpecificResource>, resource: SpecificResource): void
const test = askHydra(isSpecificHydra, resource);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=50&pln=29&pc=1#code/PTC2E8AIEEAUElIGcCmA7AJkyoWQE4pID2ArvgMZGQDuAlgC4AWkAEuBvgIaQBmx%20UFwYAaWkzoUWTLtiGZhAqAAd8xZSnwM61FADoA5nsgADAAINwGk3oCwAKDpoGm3lypsO3AEpEylPABvB0hQyAByCysUcIAuZAZ8JwMAbgcAXwcHEGJeSAp-VEhmIjxCEnIqbBR3aS4ANzweDDpeXk10BmQULtzIVXVNbSIxJg7IOkguDAwpyDRSXCSKUzoMEwcnF3w3DwBlDQpWyV8KgMgUAA8XTGx2Ti5T-w9g%20zCJjHiF0AAjTTT7Jl7NlgCU%20MQADYQ4j0NAGPikNAUbTENDVWrFLgAayaBD8lTwDGIkGh8J4EKceCcxTG%20VRJAhKAcvERyLoqImSHu3AAFOVnih4tzHviAgBKSCvd4FNGQ-SknkmZh0bAqqZoSBMLw8fkEyB9SwaSAAEkCuoCAG1IoaYgBddImMUAoEspEojUqg4oI68STCvmiqjxL0%20k6BlASqVhGUM%20XEAyK5Wq7A8JCHY4rLUPPFnDz0ZgfE1m8N6NYOp0ZLL2EBoGEknrhbAUQjCXEhjM5gUOGNdc1ByDt30UJ56gC8kpCYWt0TiEUHknCIknoTW8QAjEvAQCQSQ%20Fx8GIrjcWnCJs5XO48BhiNQwQArYg-TZc7UB3MRgGe9ND-19j9Vms60ZBhG0gDAUF9NBcVdNkOXzFgeFYLhMEZfAETddkNVkfp9y4XBtgcG02GQjBUIAHgAFQua50CwTwHhHAIAD5IHHN94goiVRxY%20piDWAEYPdKYkCxYVKOo487m1RiqCYnkYKFEjyIopixD-DjI2XdCKDfAUK0BADQQkZN9SxBxZFE18VWFNTw30kAflILoxkIMQkJQzRimiMCb2wWsui4KE6x4QTMJpYRMRxFMJNolBZi2C8PGw5RcPwzRu3pLoXCQLpxws-0v29DMbM7AknSAA)

Comment: Eh, indeed, it seems that TS can infer the type just fine by itself, that's good to know  Thanks!